# .PDB Files are not capable of importing to blender 2.8

Tags: modeling, import

[image] 
.pdb files arent able to import to 2.8 due to unicode decoding error

Does anybody have a solution for this because not one .pdb file is working. I can make the molecules but long term, this would be an issue for massive proteins that people have put months of work into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your files have the wrong encoding. The byte `0xFF` is [not valid in UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences). You need to convert the file to UTF-8 then it should work properly. A good editor will be able to do this for you, for example Notepad++ offers a function to convert encodings.

Comment: so why does it work in 2.79 but not 2.8?

Comment: also, that didnt work. when I went to encoding-> convert to utf-8, then back to blender, it gives the same error.

Comment: Does the exact same file work in 2.79? You need to save the file after the conversion, it doesn't auto-save. Did you do that?

Comment: yes it did, but the notepad++ (after saving the changes) did work. I have no idea why the files aren't interpreted by both versions the same way though.

Comment: @Kaleljordan The only reason I can imagine is that the add-on in 2.79 simply ignored/skipped what couldn't be decoded instead of throwing an exception. I would have to test this with a wrongly encoded file and step through both add-on versions to give a definitive answer. As a rule of thumb though, if it's not UTF-8 then Blender won't process it.